# MIDP Java implementation of SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, java-me, midp, rms

Are there any MIDP implementation of SQLite db available for use of sqlite db within a MIDlet, rather than using RMS. Of course, there are [Floggy](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/) and [OpenBaseMovil](http://www.openbasemovil.org), however they are based on RMS, but are there any implementations that allows to perform operations in an sqlite db file?

Comment: http://SQLjet.com provides some api in java to works with SQLite Databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing something like that:

- take the open source code of SQLite (written in C) and write something similar in JavaME. nobody has done that yet. There is an ongoing effort to write a version of SQLite in C# for windows mobile but you have got to wonder what impact a move to an interpreted language with no control over the performance of file system access will have.
- define and implement a JavaME API that accesses the native SQLite via something like JNI. This is usually extremely complicated if you are not the phone manufacturer or one of its very close partners. I suspect Android does that so you could look at its sources in that area but it won't be MIDP-compliant. There are no official JSR for an SQLite-like API yet.

Answer (score 1):

J2ME spec does not define JNI. Being an ISV and trying to write native bindings is out of question. Sun's reference implementation does define something called KNI - but then you have to be an OEM to be able to do that and ship the VM with the phone.

Comment: True, however, QuickRecipeOnSymbian's first option seems viable