# How to use SQLite database in JME?

Tags: sqlite, java-me

How to use SQLite database in JME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the previous 2 questions on the subject:

[sqlite-and-j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048994/sqlite-and-j2me/1057632)

and

[midp-java-implementation-of-sqlite-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277308/midp-java-implementation-of-sqlite-db/1277379)